# How to make dropdownlist item's unselectable,once it has been selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

---

```
                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>

                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>

                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
```

I have one dropdownlist in my form in .aspx File.

Once I select "1", then next time if I redirect to same page then "1" should be

unselectable or Hidden for making sense that I have selected "1"  previously because I have large items in my example.

Comment: How are you tracking that they have previously selected it?

Comment: Not possible to make `not-selectable` in asp.net dropdown list. **Though it is possible in `HTML Generic Controls`**. But you can remove the item from the list when you click on the list item.

Comment: I think he meant to disable the dropdown itself, @krshekhar

Comment: Use JQuery store the value in a hidden Control (ie or another select), and on page load make bind a method to this Select, so that whenever the user makes a selection, you compare what is in the "hidden Control"... Hope this helps

Comment: He does not want to remove the item from the list, so that it still shows as it is there, and still does not want the whole Dropdown list disabled. so I guess Jquery is the solution

Comment: @Has Taiar :can you put code,if it is possible,i am new to JQuery..

Answer (score 1):

Disabling any particular item in a dropdownlist is not possible.

Alternate:

You can use a **`BulletedList`** `Server Control` and use its `Enable = False` property to disable any particular item and all user can see that item as disabled.. here is a design time example..

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Enabled="False">3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

Took from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1132654.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field to store which item was selected in code behind and disable that item using the following code.

```
//Code Starts
$(document).ready(function() {   
   $('#ddlList option:contains("HTML")').attr("disabled","disabled");
});​
//Code Ends
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track your selection using Cookies, 
on the `"onChange"` event of your dropdown list, create a cookie with the selected value,
then on body `"onLoad"` u can check and disable the items that are there in Cookie.

Or you can hold your selected values in a hidden field

Answer (score 0):

To **remove the last selected item** in your dropdownlist (DDL), considering the following code for your DDL form, you can use the **onselectedindexchanged** event of your DDL (that is raised when you click on one of your DDL items):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="_DDL" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And put on the code behind the **RemoveAt()** method to remove the selected Item from your DDL:

```
        protected void _DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ItemToRemove = _DDL.SelectedIndex;
        _DDL.Items.RemoveAt(ItemToRemove);
    }
```

Hope this will be helpful :)